# selenium python automatically closing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using selenium I am new in this so can someone help me? When I run, the website is automatically closing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPo3l.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using 'https' instead of httpps, this may be the cause of the problem.